# "Upcoming Events" includes ongoing events?

Tags: word-usage

StackOverflow opened [Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314186/2818869) from yesterday and a banner is up that says:

[image]

...Upcoming? The survey is ongoing.

Is "upcoming" not only for future (=not yet) stuffs?

Comment: Upcoming means about to happen, forthcoming. If you say "the upcoming election", the election will be held in the future very soon. Those events will be held in the foreseeable future or soon.

Comment: Just guessing...maybe they didn't update the banner ? Upcoming has only one meaning and I'm sure you can find it in any dictionary.

Comment: @VarunKN This banner area lists future events and ongoing events. So I want to know this is common usage or not.

Comment: No, upcoming strictly means "in the future". Be it in the next decade or in the next 1/10000000000th second, its still a word that is used to refer a future time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upcoming does not mean ongoing. An event that happens in the future is upcoming, when that event starts to happen in the present tense it becomes *ongoing*. Then when that event ends it would be *finished*.

That screenshot from stack overflow is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming-dates calendar would more appropriately be titled "Upcoming Dates" or just "Calendar," and omit the misleading and unnecessary word "Events."